# Consuming a Kafka Topic from Salesforce

Tags: apache-kafka, salesforce, kafka-consumer-api, apex, apache-kafka-connect

We have a microservice architecture and we want to publish events into Kafka topics to then be consumed by Salesforce. What is the best approach to do this ? Is there any example Apex code that do that ?

Best Regards.

Comment: There's a Kafka connector that you might find useful https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-salesforce

Answer (score 2):

Kafka Salesforce connector paid version is available on [Confluent Connector Hub](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-salesforce).As of now ,Kafka Salesforce connector is not available on any Open Source Platforms but some source code is available on GitHub. You can use and customized the code according to your requirement.

https://github.com/Entanet/kafka-salesforce-connect

https://github.com/nodefluent/salesforce-kafka-connect

https://javalibs.com/artifact/com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect/kafka-connect-salesforce

Answer (score 2):

Please note that most Salesforce Kafka connectors are using the Salesforce Streaming API for which following limits apply and might be very limiting:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.188.0.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/limits.htm